# Porting Python to D: urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, d

I wrote a program in Python recently (Windows 64-bit v3.3.1), and am attempting to port it to D.  The problem I have run into is that I make use of the `urllib` module in Python, in particular, `urllib.request.Request` and `urllib.request.urlopen`, and I haven't been able to find an equivalent in D.

Does D have a library that serves a similar purpose?  If not, how do I go about achieving the same functionality?  (All I need to do is to download a .csv file and then parse it into an array of dictionaries.)

EDIT:  I originally tried Idan's suggestion of importing `std.net.curl`, but I ran into issues.  I had a problem with linking `libcurl` at first, but then I managed to build it and put it in my lib' folder, which got rid of that error. Then I got a couple of .dll errors, and after putting the appropriate .dll files in what (I thought) were the appropriate directories, I still got an error: "The procedure entry EVP_md2 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\libssl32.dll.". Note that `libss3l2.dll` was one of the .dll files I had to download.  Also, all these errors (except the `libcurl' linking errors) occurred during run-time, as soon as the program launched, so it did managed to actually build just fine.

Comment: you could manually set up the minimalist http request and force the response encoding into something you can handle

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I'm not sure what I did wrong initially, but I wound up deleting the `curl.lib` I produced the first time around and all copies of `libssl32.dll`.  The copy of libcurl I downloaded this around time can be gotten [here](http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.30.0/dist-w32/curl-7.30.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-idn-static-bin-w32.zip).  (I forget what version I downloaded the first time, but I think my problems might simply be a result of me getting the wrong version the first time around.)

Then, I built `curl.lib' using

```
libimp.exe /s curl.lib libcurl.dll
```

(`libimp` is a utility for D that can be found [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/download/freecompiler.html).), and put `curl.lib` into `DMD\windows\lib\`.

Finally, I copied all .dlls in the root of the libccurl download and put them in the folder with the executable I was trying to build.  I then built the project again and it ran just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `std.net.curl` - http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html

Note that you need to link to `libcurl` in order to use it. You can download it from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html - look for "Win32 - Generic"

Comment: I tried this.  I had a problem with `libcurl' at first, but then I managed to build it and put it in my `lib' folder, which got rid of that error.  Then I got a couple of .dll errors, and after putting the appropriate .dll files in what (I thought) were the appropriate directories, I still got an error:  "The procedure entry EVP_md2 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\libss32.dll.".  Note that `libss32.dll` was one of the .dll files I had to download.

Comment: I think I will add this extra info to the original question so that it's easier to find.

Comment: I managed to run it on my work Windows box with just `libcurl.dll`. Put it in your project's directory, and link it via `pragma(lib,"curl");`

Comment: Try compiling with the -m32 flag. Or to download the Win64 version of libcurl(MinGW64, not Generic - Generic does not have the DLL).